# FOSRestBundle : Upload an image using json

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle

I have been working on FOSRestBundle for some times now. I got the hang of it (forms, validation, documentation, url...).
I would like to be able to upload an image for a User using json.

I think I have done everything needed on the symfony side, it works great using a form.
I tried to find out how to specify an image using json in some previous post, but I wasn't succefull trying it.

To upload an image using the form:

1 - I get the image

2 - Move it in the right directory

3 - Add the unique name of the file in the Database

In my user entity class I have two variables one classical "string" and one "file":

```
@Assert\File (maxSize="6000000", mimeType={"image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"})
```

In my formType I have :

```
->add('file', 'file')
```

I think I just need to know how to **specify the file information and data in json** using symfony2 and FOSRestBundle

Does anyone have an idea?

**edit** :

I have been searching around and I found the class:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadFile
```

and

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File
```

But I still can't make it work, anyone as a clue to help me work this out?

Comment: I'm not sure, but AFAIK json is not suitable for binary data.

Comment: I looked around and some people used it and it seemed to work.
I just didn't found any working example for symfony2 and FOSRest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to user base64_encode and decode functions combine with file_get_contents and file_put_contents($this->getAbsolutePath(), $decoded);

Let me know if you have issue regarding this.